# How can I write this logic in C

Tags: c

Consider a hypothetical programming language with following rules:

Each function starts with the keyword “BEGIN” and then its name 
At the end of each function, there must be the keyword “END”.

To call a function, the keyword “CALL” is used just before the name of the function.The keyword “EXECUTE” means that: “do some work without the help of another function”.

The word "done" is not our concern in this assignment! 
A program always starts with the line: “BEGIN Main”.

Assume that some code is written with respect to the rules described above and stored in a file called “code.prog” In this file, also assume that there exist a “line number” at the start of each line.

Write a C program which reads this code (code.prog) and prints the execution with line numbers.
For this job, you are supposed to create a stack of line numbers for function calls.Therefore, in addition, print the contents of the stack for each “function call” and “function end”.

```
EXAMPLE
code.prg  // this is the file
1 BEGIN Fun1  
2  CALL Fun2 
3  EXECUTE 
4 END  
5 BEGIN Fun2  
6  EXECUTE 
7 END  
8 BEGIN Main  
9  EXECUTE 
10  CALL Fun1 
11 END
```

Output of the code :

```
Execution Order of Lines: 
8    
9    
10 Stack = 10  
1    
2 Stack = 2 10 
5    
6    
7 Stack = 10  
3    
4 Stack =    
11  --- END ---
```

Comment: It is not a programming contest site where you give a problem and user solve. There is many tutorial and online programming contest site available. Try it out there and if you fall in error in some portion then come back we will try to solve that error.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/QotaSJ)

Answer (score 1):

You should know how programming languages are parsed and executed.
I recommend you to read "Concepts, Models and Techniques of Computer Programming" by Peter Van Roy, if you want deeper information.

Your programming language is constructed by syntax, semantic and pragmatics. Your assignment text describes the grammatic rules of your programming language (syntax). These rules are useful for writing valid senteces in your languages. 
Valid sentences can be understood by your interpreter and then executed.
During the execution, you are basically assigning a semantic meaning to each sentence.

These are the steps:

1. Write a tokenizer. Each word of your programming language is a token. `BEGIN` is a token, `CALL` is a token, function names are token too (function identifiers). The tokenizer analyses your source code (which is a simple string) and creates a list of tokens.
   `Text files -> [TOKENIZER] -> sequence of token`
2. Write a parser. Sentences are composed by words, then similarly your P.L sentences will be composed by tokens. You should use your grammar rules in order to know which sequence of token are valid and which are not. E.g. functions has to begin with `BEGIN` token, followed by a `identifier` token, followed by one or more `instruction` token and ending with the `END` token. You have to create a **parse tree** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree). The nodes of the parse tree are non-terminator symbols, the leaves are terminator symbols (tokens).
   `Sequence of token -> [PARSER] -> Parse tree`
3. Write an interpreter. It's time to assign the semantic to each symbol: starting at the root of the parsing tree, the interpreter analyses each node executing the related instruction.

Implementation:

The tokenizer and the parser are just Finite State Machines.
The interpreter is basically a program that converts a parse tree in an execution stack, from which each instruction is poped out and executed.